# Showing that map $\phi(z)=z(z-1)$ is not covering projection

Tags: algebraic-topology

Map $\phi : \mathbb{C} - \{0,1/2\} \to \mathbb{C} - \{-1/4\}$ given by $\phi(z)=z(z-1)$ is not covering projection. Can someone give hint how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

For $z \in \mathbb C \setminus \{0, -1/4\}$, the inverse image of $z$ under $\phi$ includes two points. However, the inverse image of $0$ is equal to $\{0,1\}$ but $0$ has been excluded from the definition set of $\phi$.

Comment: Oh yes. Codomain is connected so cardinality of fibres should be same for each point.